# Why have an API and an implementation?

Tags: oop, interface, implementation

Many times, I've seen single class (Java) implement a single interface. That interface is only used for the single class. No other class implements it. Why do we do this? It seems like to me, we don't need the interface, just the class.

Example: https://github.com/essentials/Essentials/blob/2.x/Essentials/src/com/earth2me/essentials/I18n.java

Comment: I need an example before I can think about this queston.

Comment: @a_river_in_canada I added one

Comment: You have only one implementation *now*... Some people like to be super future-compatible. Whether this is always the most efficient approach is debatable of course...

Comment: @deceze How is this future-compatible?

Comment: Because maybe you want to write a second implementation against the interface *later*...

Comment: Testing, and the ability to mock lower level components.  See the D in SOLID https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)

Comment: Many people do it because they've read or heard somewhere that it is considered best practice.  I don't buy the future proofing argument, and depending on the language, not even the unit testing one.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the language for a sec.

There are many reasons to use interfaces and having just one class implement an interface is absolutely fine.

Imagine you want to write testable code, you want to do all the good stuff, have tests etc.

A good way to write code is to never ever hard-code any dependencies in a class. It makes life a lot easier if you inject dependencies and that is done via an interface or abstract class. So you basically never say hey class, here's a cat implementation, you say hey here's a generic animal, use that.

The interface has that one job to provide a contract and that's what you are using. You are thus decoupling your code from dependencies, so now you're able to test it and you can mock all your dependencies easily. The fact that you have one or more implementation makes no difference whatsoever.

Comment: "A good way to write code is to never ever hard-code any dependencies in a class." - I just want to add that it is also good to write code that is pragmatic, and simple.  Some hard coded dependencies are more pragmatic and more simple then depending on injected interfaces.